# Access Home Webserver behind DSLite via Relay Server

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, relay

So I have this connection where I don't get a public IPv4 address, only a IPv6 from my provider, and every IPv4 traffic is tunneled to their Server and translated to v4 via NAT (and back). Now, I wanted to try to host my own Webserver in my Home Network, just for learning and practicing purposes (and disconnect it once I got it working, I understand there are Security issues).
So, I am running the default IIS site on my Windows PC on port 80. Since my router only has a public 6 address I bought a cheap little cloud hosted machine that I wanna use as a relay server. I gave it a public 4 and 6 address, installed 6tunnel and ran the command *6tunnel 80 my_IPv6_Address 80* . Then I activated Port forwarding on my Router for all incoming IPv6 packets on port 80 to my PC.

Now, when I go to the browser and visit my Relay server under it's ipv4 address, I don't get a connection, I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. What am I missing / doing wrong here? I can ping both v4 and v6 addresses of my relay, and my relay can ping my router. Web doesn't work though.

Thanks for helping a noob out :D